# "Unsupported case for discriminated type" when reading tag from Allen Bradley's Micro820 PLC, using Apache's PLC4X

Tags: apache-plc4x, plc4x

I’m using Apache’s PLC4X library in order to read some tags from an Allen Bradley’s Micro820 PLC (2080-LC20-20QWB). So far, I am able to establish a connection with the device but when I try to execute a read request I’m getting the error shown in the stack trace bellow.

I’m running a Java maven based project with the following dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.plc4x</groupId>
            <artifactId>plc4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Ethernet / IP driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.plc4x</groupId>
            <artifactId>plc4j-driver-eip</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is the code I'm running on a Ubuntu 18.04 width JDK 11

```
package com.example.plctest;

import org.apache.plc4x.java.PlcDriverManager;
import org.apache.plc4x.java.api.PlcConnection;
import org.apache.plc4x.java.api.messages.PlcReadRequest;
import org.apache.plc4x.java.api.messages.PlcReadResponse;
import org.apache.plc4x.java.eip.readwrite.field.EipField;
import org.apache.plc4x.java.eip.readwrite.types.CIPDataTypeCode;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class ReadPlcDemo {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReadPlcDemo.class);
    private static String connectionString = "eip://192.168.1.100?backplane=0&slot=0";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Establish a connection with the PLC
        try (PlcConnection connection = new PlcDriverManager().getConnection(connectionString)) {
            if (connection.getMetadata().canRead()) {
                LOGGER.info("PLC can read!");
            }
            // Create the read request
            EipField field = new EipField("Sensor1", CIPDataTypeCode.BOOL);
            // EipField field = new EipField("Sensor2", CIPDataTypeCode.SINT);
            // EipField field = new EipField("Sensor3", CIPDataTypeCode.SINT);
            PlcReadRequest.Builder builder = connection.readRequestBuilder();
            builder.addItem("value-" + field.getTag(), field);
            PlcReadRequest readRequest = builder.build();
            // Execute the request
            PlcReadResponse response;
            try {
                response = readRequest.execute().get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result from my stack trace, I set the log level to 'trace' in order to get a better insight of what's going on:

```
/home/ghinojosa/.jdks/corretto-11.0.14.1/bin/java -Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true --add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED -javaagent:/home/ghinojosa/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/213.6777.52/lib/idea_rt.jar=44017:/home/ghinojosa/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/213.6777.52/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/ghinojosa/IdeaProjects/plc-test/target/classes:/home/ghinojosa/Downloads/eeip-library.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/org/apache/plc4x/plc4j-api/0.9.1/plc4j-api-0.9.1.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0/commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.12.5/jackson-annotations-2.12.5.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/org/apache/plc4x/plc4j-driver-eip/0.9.1/plc4j-driver-eip-0.9.1.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/org/apache/plc4x/plc4j-spi/0.9.1/plc4j-spi-0.9.1.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec/4.1.67.Final/netty-codec-4.1.67.Final.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.1.67.Final/netty-common-4.1.67.Final.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport/4.1.67.Final/netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-resolver/4.1.67.Final/netty-resolver-4.1.67.Final.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.4/commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.12.5/jackson-core-2.12.5.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.12.5/jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/io/vavr/vavr/0.10.4/vavr-0.10.4.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/io/vavr/vavr-match/0.10.4/vavr-match-0.10.4.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/com/github/jinahya/bit-io/1.4.3/bit-io-1.4.3.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.15/commons-codec-1.15.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/org/apache/plc4x/plc4j-transport-tcp/0.9.1/plc4j-transport-tcp-0.9.1.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.1.67.Final/netty-buffer-4.1.67.Final.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.8.0-beta4/slf4j-api-1.8.0-beta4.jar:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.8.0-beta4/slf4j-simple-1.8.0-beta4.jar com.example.plctest.ReadPlcDemo
[main] INFO org.apache.plc4x.java.PlcDriverManager - Instantiating new PLC Driver Manager with class loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5c8da962
[main] INFO org.apache.plc4x.java.PlcDriverManager - Registering available drivers...
[main] INFO org.apache.plc4x.java.PlcDriverManager - Registering driver for Protocol eip (EthernetIP)
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.targetRecords: 4
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory - Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@4de5031f
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - Java version: 11
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/home/ghinojosa/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.1.67.Final/netty-common-4.1.67.Final.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - direct buffer constructor: available
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): available
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): available
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - maxDirectMemory: 8390705152 bytes (maybe)
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: /tmp (java.io.tmpdir)
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: 8390705152 bytes
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: 1024
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.CleanerJava9 - java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available
[main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 8
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.initialSize: 1024
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.maxSize: 4096
[main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
[main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
[main] TRACE io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@76505305
[main] TRACE io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@7b98f307
[main] TRACE io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@4802796d
[main] TRACE io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@34123d65
[main] TRACE io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@59474f18
[main] TRACE io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@65fb9ffc
[main] TRACE io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@3e694b3f
[main] TRACE io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@1bb5a082
[main] INFO org.apache.plc4x.java.transport.tcp.TcpChannelFactory - Configuring Bootstrap with org.apache.plc4x.java.eip.readwrite.configuration.EIPConfiguration@5aa9e4eb
[main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.processId: 10908 (auto-detected)
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack: false
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses: false
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtilInitializations - Loopback interface: lo (lo, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo)
[main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn: 4096
[main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.machineId: f4:06:69:ff:fe:d6:97:69 (auto-detected)
[main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 8
[main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 8
[main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192
[main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 11
[main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 16777216
[main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256
[main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
[main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
[main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
[main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimIntervalMillis: 0
[main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.useCacheForAllThreads: true
[main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedByteBuffersPerChunk: 1023
[main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
[main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 0
[main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
[main] TRACE org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.connection.DefaultNettyPlcConnection - Channel was created, firing ChannelCreated Event
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.Plc4xNettyWrapper - User Event triggered org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.events.ConnectEvent@645e8927
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG org.apache.plc4x.java.eip.readwrite.protocol.EipProtocolLogic - Sending RegisterSession EIP Package
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.Plc4xNettyWrapper - Adding Response Handler ...
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.Plc4xNettyWrapper - Sending to wire EipConnectionRequest[sessionHandle=0,status=0,senderContext={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},options=0]
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.Plc4xNettyWrapper - Forwarding request to plc EipConnectionRequest[sessionHandle=0,status=0,senderContext={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},options=0]
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 4096
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.delayedQueue.ratio: 8
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf - -Dio.netty.buffer.checkAccessible: true
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf - -Dio.netty.buffer.checkBounds: true
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory - Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@20edcbc7
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.GeneratedDriverByteToMessageCodec - Sending bytes to PLC for message EipConnectionRequest[sessionHandle=0,status=0,senderContext={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},options=0] as data 65000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.GeneratedDriverByteToMessageCodec - Receiving bytes, trying to decode Message...
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.Plc4xNettyWrapper - Decoding EipConnectionRequest[sessionHandle=3604940806,status=0,senderContext={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},options=0]
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.Plc4xNettyWrapper - Checking handler HandlerRegistration#0 for Object of type EipConnectionRequest
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.Plc4xNettyWrapper - Handler HandlerRegistration#0 has right expected type EipPacket, checking condition
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.Plc4xNettyWrapper - Handler HandlerRegistration#0 accepts element EipConnectionRequest[sessionHandle=3604940806,status=0,senderContext={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},options=0], calling handle method
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG org.apache.plc4x.java.eip.readwrite.protocol.EipProtocolLogic - Got assigned with Session 3604940806
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.Plc4xNettyWrapper - Firing Connected!
[main] INFO com.example.plctest.ReadPlcDemo - PLC can read!
[main] TRACE org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.transaction.RequestTransactionManager - Submission of transaction 0
[pool-2-thread-1] TRACE org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.transaction.RequestTransactionManager - Start execution of transaction 0
[pool-2-thread-1] TRACE org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.Plc4xNettyWrapper - Adding Response Handler ...
[pool-2-thread-1] TRACE org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.transaction.RequestTransactionManager - Completed execution of transaction 0
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.Plc4xNettyWrapper - Forwarding request to plc CipRRData[sessionHandle=3604940806,status=0,senderContext={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},options=0,exchange=CipExchange[service=CipUnconnectedRequest[unconnectedService=CipReadRequest[RequestPathSize=5,tag={-111,7,83,101,110,115,111,114,49,0},elementNb=1],backPlane=0,slot=0]]]
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.GeneratedDriverByteToMessageCodec - Sending bytes to PLC for message CipRRData[sessionHandle=3604940806,status=0,senderContext={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},options=0,exchange=CipExchange[service=CipUnconnectedRequest[unconnectedService=CipReadRequest[RequestPathSize=5,tag={-111,7,83,101,110,115,111,114,49,0},elementNb=1],backPlane=0,slot=0]]] as data 6f002c000608dfd600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000b2001c00520220062401059d0e004c05910753656e736f723100010001000000
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.GeneratedDriverByteToMessageCodec - Receiving bytes, trying to decode Message...
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] INFO org.apache.plc4x.java.eip.readwrite.io.CipRRDataIO - Expected constant value 0 but got 5 for reserved field.
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] WARN org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.GeneratedDriverByteToMessageCodec - Error decoding package with content [6f0016000608dfd600000000000000000000000000000000000000000500020000000000b2000600d20001011103]: Unsupported case for discriminated type
org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.generation.ParseException: Unsupported case for discriminated type
    at org.apache.plc4x.java.eip.readwrite.io.CipServiceIO.staticParse(CipServiceIO.java:100)
    at org.apache.plc4x.java.eip.readwrite.io.CipExchangeIO.staticParse(CipExchangeIO.java:96)
    at org.apache.plc4x.java.eip.readwrite.io.CipRRDataIO.staticParse(CipRRDataIO.java:80)
    at org.apache.plc4x.java.eip.readwrite.io.EipPacketIO.staticParse(EipPacketIO.java:101)
    at org.apache.plc4x.java.eip.readwrite.io.EipPacketIO.parse(EipPacketIO.java:48)
    at org.apache.plc4x.java.eip.readwrite.io.EipPacketIO.parse(EipPacketIO.java:42)
    at org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.GeneratedDriverByteToMessageCodec.decode(GeneratedDriverByteToMessageCodec.java:79)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageCodec$1.decode(ByteToMessageCodec.java:42)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageCodec.channelRead(ByteToMessageCodec.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I'd appreciate any help or if someone could point me in the right direction, in terms of how to solve this. Thanks in advance!
Guillermo

Comment: Can you bring this to our mailinglist dev@plc4x.apache.org? Thank you! -> Additionally we have a Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/PLC4X/issues/PLC4X-338?filter=allopenissues

Comment: Ok, I will take this issue to the mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same issue:
Apparently, from what I've read, the Micro820 series have limitations reading tags. In the case of the PLC I was using (2080-LC20-20QWB) I had to:

1. Establish a session by sending a "Forward_Open" request. The details of the request is in page 105 of the [CIP specification](https://manualzz.com/doc/42538578/the-cip-networks-library-volume-1-common-industrial).
2. Once the connection is established, multiple "Read Data" requests can be send with the names of the tags that you wish the read.
3. Finally, a "Forward_Close" request is send in order to close the connection.

And that's it.

I cloned [this project](https://github.com/ornl-epics/etherip) and implemented the steps that I just described. You can find my version [here](https://github.com/ghinojosa/etherip).
And here's an example showing how to use it:

```
 try {
        EtherNetIP plc = new EtherNetIP("10.0.1.100", 0);
        plc.connectTcp();
        List<TagReadReply> tags = plc.connectAndReadTags("Sensor1", "Sensor2" , "Sensor10");
        tags.forEach(each -> {
            logger.info("Tag name:" + each.getTag() + " is valid ? " + each.isValid());
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.severe("Exception occurred:" + e.getMessage());
    }
```